# Electron error Function must be called on an object of type NativeImage

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am working with electron and reactjs and rendering the view with electron js, I am facing an `Error: Illegal invocation: Function must be called on an object of type NativeImage` after electron version upgrade. I can't downgrade the electron version as some functionality is not working in surface machines.

We have the functionality to capture screenshots but after the package upgrade facing an error while screenshot capture. I am using webview to render view in the electron application.

Here is the code how I am using to load view in webview.

```
const webview = <webview src="path" class="webview__3kBDE" style="width: 768px; height: 576px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></webview>

const rawImage = await webview.capturePage()
const URL = rawImage.toPNG()
```

When I am printing the `rawImage` I am getting blank object so while `rawImage.toPNG()` I am facing an error. If anyone has any idea how to fix this error that would be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: Experiencing same issue when calling .toDataURL() from renderer process… that said, calling same function from main works so either this is a bug or a context limitation (see [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34953)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Electron 10 release had major changes and if you are using the Electron 10 > the remote module is now disabled by default. To use the remote module, enableRemoteModule: true must be specified in WebPreferences:

```
const w = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
    enableRemoteModule: true
   }
})
```

For more details check here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#default-changed-enableremotemodule-defaults-to-false